# Getting coordinates and population of all cities in a country

Tags: google-maps, maps, geography

Can I get something like that on any of google services? or is there another place that can help me?

I need both coordinates and population but most of the lists I find are either one or another and have completely different formats.

Is there a website that can help me?

Answer (score -1):

There's no such API where you can get both coordinates and population.

For the coordinates or any geographical information regarding a specific place or country, you may use **[Google Maps Platform API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation)**.

With regards to the population and you think that it, I would suggest to file for a **[Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com)** to include population (*like estimate number people for a particular place/city/area/region/country*) on the response in our Google **Public Issue Tracker**.

**[Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/)** is a tool used internally at Google to track bugs and feature requests during product development. It is available outside of Google for use by external public and partner users who need to collaborate with Google teams on specific projects.

Hope this information could be helpful on your side.